# Craigslist, CURL, Simple PHP DOM Issues

Tags: html, dom, curl, craigslist

I am logging into Craigslist with CURL to scrape the status of my posted listings.  The problem I encounter is the transfer of HTML from CURL $output to file_get_html.  While Craigslist statuses are actually nested inside TR elements, I just wanted to test the most basic functions to see if things were getting passed through (i.e. link scraping).  They are not.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
$cookie_file_path = getcwd()."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.craigslist.org/login?LoginType=L&step=confirmation&originalURI=%2Flogin&rt=&rp=&inputEmailHandle='.$email.'&inputPassword='.$password.'&submit=Log%20In');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.craigslist.org');

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;

//

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($output);
//find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

I know the expression works because it returns links if I put in 'http://google.com', or something or other.

Comment: Are you sure cURL has correctly logged in?

Comment: Absolutely positive.  Echoing the output displays my account page.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be done

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.sitename.com');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);  

$html= str_get_html($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using str_get_html instead of file_get_html?
Since $ouput is a string!